# Matplotlib prevent <use> elements in an SVG file

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, graph

I have a python script that uses matplotlib.pyplot to generate an SVG file with a graph. I want to use that graph with three.js.
This creates a problem since three.js does not handle the `<use>` element which gives me a lot of nothing since this file is full of them.

To generate the file I do nothing special:

```
plt.savefig('output.svg')
```

How can I prevent matplotlib from using the `<use>` element and instead create duplicate elements?

Alternatively does anyone know of an easy way to replace the elements using inkscape or some other tool/lib?

Comment: What elements are those? What are "duplicate elements"? Can you show a minimal code that produces the unwanted elements and clearly describe how you would like the output to look like instead?

Comment: I see. There is at least no solution from within matplotlib.